# Randomly copy a rectangular random region and paste it on another image in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I've been trying copy a rectangular random region with width and height in [128, 1024] but sometimes I run into

```
---> 29 I_rcv[a:b, c:d] = dnr_patch
     30 pyplot.imshow(I_rcv)

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (425,91,3) into shape (959,91,3)
```

Here's my code

```
rcv = "path/to/image/RCV.JPG"
dnr_1 = "path/to/image/DNR.JPG"

I_rcv = cv2.imread(rcv)
I_dnr = cv2.imread(dnr_1)
a = random.randint(0, min(I_dnr.shape[0] - 1024, I_rcv.shape[0] - 1024))
b = a + random.randint(1, 1024)
c = random.randint(0, min(I_dnr.shape[0] - 128, I_rcv.shape[0] - 128))
d = c + random.randint(1, 128)
dnr_patch = np.copy(I_dnr[a:b,c:d])
I_rcv[a:b, c:d] = dnr_patch
```

Edit:
Following are variable values. Images are of random shape, I need to pick donor image, crop a patch and place it to receiver.

```
I_rcv: (3648, 2736, 3)
I_dnr: (2304, 3072, 3)
dnr_patch: (425, 91, 3)
```

Comment: On which line does the error occur?  What makes the error occur (or not occur)?

Comment: @JohnZwinck Oops! Forgot to add last line. `I_rcv[a:b, c:d] = dnr_patch`

Comment: OK, then when it fails, what are `a,b,c,d` and `I_rcv.shape` and `I_dnr.shape`?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `c = random.randint(0, min(I_dnr.shape[1] - 128, I_rcv.shape[1] - 128))`?

Comment: @JohnZwinck `I_rcv: (3648, 2736, 3)`,  `I_dnr: (2304, 3072, 3)`, `dnr_patch: (425, 91, 3)`.

Comment: @PaulPanzer Yes, you are right. I've made those corrections but I still get those errors.

Comment: @ManishYadav: We need to know the example values of `a,b,c,d` that cause an error, and the shape of the arrays from that same run.